# Нулевой объект при получении местоположения. google map

Tags: android

Проблема кажется весьма банальной, но я пока так и не могу ее решить.

При включенном gps, моб. интернет, wi-fi ( одно из трех ), приложение работает, но как только все отключаешь и пробуешь заново перезапустить приложение, вылетает "Приложение остановлено". Ошибка банальна "null object".

Прикладываю код

```
// Готовность карты
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: map is ready");
    mMap = googleMap;

    if (mLocationPermissionsGranted) {
        getDeviceLocation();

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

    }
}

private static final String TAG = "MapActivity";

private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
private static final String COURSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
private static final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 17f;

private Boolean mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
private GoogleMap mMap;
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;

private ImageButton buttonGoProfile;
private ImageButton buttonCreationBeen;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    buttonGoProfile = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonGoProfile);
    buttonCreationBeen = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddPost);

    getLocationPermission();

    buttonGoProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ProfileUserActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    buttonCreationBeen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MakeRecordActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

// Получение местоположения
private void getDeviceLocation(){
    Log.d(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: getting the devices current location");

    mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    try{
        if(mLocationPermissionsGranted){

            final Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
            location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: found location!");
                        Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();
                        moveCamera(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()),
                                DEFAULT_ZOOM);

                        }
                    }else{
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: current location is null");
                        Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "unable to get current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }catch (SecurityException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: SecurityException: " + e.getMessage() );
    }
}


// Камера
private void moveCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom){
    Log.d(TAG, "moveCamera: moving the camera to: lat: " + latLng.latitude + ", lng: " + latLng.longitude );
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));
}

//Инициализация карты
private void initMap(){
    Log.d(TAG, "initMap: initializing map");
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapActivity.this);
}

// Получение разрешения на получение местоположения
private void getLocationPermission(){
    Log.d(TAG, "getLocationPermission: getting location permissions");
    String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
            FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                COURSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
            initMap();
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    permissions,
                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }else{
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                permissions,
                LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

// Получение результата разрешения
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: called.");
    mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;

    switch(requestCode){
        case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:{
            if(grantResults.length > 0){
                for(int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++){
                    if(grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
                        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission failed");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission granted");
                mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
                initMap();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Я нашел причину этой проблемы в этом куске

```
 if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: found location!");
                        Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();
                        moveCamera(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()),
                                DEFAULT_ZOOM);
```

currentLocation не чего не получает и проблема в этом, но как сделать корректную проверку на null? Глупый вопрос конечно, но все же прошу помощи у старших коллег.

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил. Может кому пригодиться. Проверку сделал так

```
if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null){
```

Теперь все работает корректно